# Template specialization with void function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a little program where i create a 2d array. The function itself works fine, but i get a problem when i want to implement the function in its own file. This is how it looks like:

mat.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "matdyn.hpp";

int main(){
    int row, column;
    cin >> row;
    cin >> column;

    int** M1;
    double** M2;

    reserve(M1, row, column);
    reserve(M2, row, column);

    return 0;
}
```

matdyn.hpp

```
#ifndef dyn
#define dyn
template <typename T, typename S>
void reserve(S **, T, T);
#endif
```

matdyn.cpp:

```
#include "matrix_dyn.hpp"

template <typename S, typename T>
void reserve(S **&x, T row, T column){
    x = new S*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        x[i] = new S[column];
    }
}  

template void reserve<int, int, int>(int, int, int);
template void reserve<double, int, int>(double, int, int);
```

My problem is the last part of the matdyn.cpp.
I always get error messages like:

```
error: template-id ‘reserve<int, int, int>’ for ‘void reserve(int, int, int)’ does not match any template declaration    
template void reserve<int, int, int>(int, int, int);
```

How do i write these last two lines properly? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Look for template functions inclusion model. Template definitions usually go to the header.

Comment: Also `reserve` has two template parameters but you are using three.  This will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code :

Your function `reserve` definition and declaration do not match.

I believe you wanted to write :

```
template <typename T, typename S>
void reserve(S **x, T row, T column){
```

Regarding your **explicit template function instantations** it should be done like this :

```
template void reserve<int, int>(int **, int, int);
template void reserve<int, double>(double **, int, int);
```

You have to match the template parameters given in your function declaration.

Here a [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3e4c983c11a6ee9) which compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either put the definition of your template function to the header matdyn.hpp

```
#ifndef dyn
#define dyn
template <typename S, typename T>
void reserve(S **&x, T row, T column){
    x = new S*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        x[i] = new S[column];
    }
}  

template void reserve<int, int>(int**&, int, int);
                      ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
template void reserve<double, int>(double**&, int, int);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^

#endif
```

Or include the matdyn.cpp in matdyn.hpp

```
#ifndef dyn
#define dyn
template <typename T, typename S>
void reserve(S **, T, T);

#include "matdyn.cpp"

#endif
```

As for the reason look this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Mind also the errors of your template specializations. The template parameter list of a function template specialization must match the template parameter list of the function template.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates):

> The definition of a template must be visible at the point of implicit instantiation, which is why template libraries typically provide all template definitions in the headers (e.g.most boost libraries are header-only)

Because of that, you should rather put everything in the header file, for that's the most common approach.